# How to identify a sequential characters using Regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string, and need to check if it has a sequence of characters. eg. abcde, or abcd

Let's say I need to flag strings that have a sequence of length greater than 3.

In other words, I need to flag *abcpa*, but not *abpqx*

Can I do this using RegEx?

Thanks

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool to do the job.

Comment: What do you mean by "sequence"? Any consecutive characters sequence like "klm", "hij", I presume?

Comment: Please clarify the question. What are the criteria for locating strings? You gave 3 examples, but there is no apparent correlation between them. Even the length that you mention doesn't seem to apply since you say that you don't want "abpqx". What are you looking for?

Comment: @frikozoid yes, I mean any set of three or more consecutive characters ....

Comment: if you want to find a sequence with min 3 just search for abc, if you need min 4 search for abcd, you don´t need regex for this

Comment: But the sequence needn't start with an a.... bcde, efgh etc are also sequences

Comment: @navinpai
I'm afraid you can't do that in one simple regex. You'll have 20-something combinations of 3 ascending character chains, and you'd have to list every single combination in your regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp matches sequences with at least 3 consecutive characters:

```
/(?:abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|vwx|wxy|xyz)/i
```

The following perl script checks for sequences of a specified number of consecutive characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($len, $test) = @ARGV;
my $s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
my $re = "";
for (0..length($s)-$len) {
    $re .= substr($s, $_, $len)."|";
}
chop $re;
exit 1 unless ($test =~ m/(?:$re)/i);
```

The script exits with error code 1 if no match was found and with error code 0 otherwise.

Call it like `perl script.pl <min length of sequence> <string to test>`.

Examples:

```
% perl script.pl 5 aaaabbbbeeeeehijklllmnppp && echo "match" || echo "no match"
match

% perl script.pl 6 aaaabbbbeeeeehijklllmnppp && echo "match" || echo "no match" 
no match
```

Comment: This works, I guess, but it isn't extensible is it? Tomorrow, if I need to check for 4 sequential characters, the regex match goes even longer... Was just wondering if there is a short and sweet method to check sequences.... but I guess there isn't! :(

Comment: @navinpai I added a perl script which can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is way you could do this with a regex. I have made the assumption that the sequences you are looking for must start at A. The example below in Powershell has a cut-down regex just using the first 8 characters just for speed and clarity and would need to be extended:

```
$re = "(?<=(?<=(?<=(?<=(?<=(?<=a)b?)c?)d?)e?)f?)g?"
"abcpa" -match $re
$matches # => "abc"
$matches[0].length # => 3
```

Not fully tested but I think it is OK.

Comment: Ah, but I've mentioned in the comments to the question that the sequence needn't start with an A .... Thanks anyhow! :)